# Eclipse OSGi bundle reqiure another bundle's fragment

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, osgi, guice

This might be simple question but have confused me for sometime.

I'm developing an OSGi bundle which rely on google guice. Google guice has one main bundle and several fragment like assisted inject fragment. 
In my bundle I have used the assisted inject fragment and a class that is exported from that fragment.

However in Eclipse, I can only set bundle dependency on another bundel (in this case, the guice bundle) but not directly on a fragment (assisted inject), hence Eclipse complains cannot find the class exported from the fragment.

How can I have the dependency on a bundle's fragment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an `Import-Package` dependency on the fragment's exported packages.

In fact you should use `Import-Package` for all your dependencies, and avoid `Require-Bundle` wherever possible.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a number of cases, where it cannot be avoided. E.g. if you're doing Eclipse plug-in that uses extension points, then you still need `Require-Bundle`.

Comment: Hi Tonny. You do **not** need a Require-Bundle dependency when using eclipse extension points. In fact you don't need any dependency, unless you need to implement an API or interface. Unfortunately the PDE tooling *suggests* you add a Require-Bundle, but it is not necessary .

Comment: I stand corrected. It works even without the declaration... Thanks.

Comment: But the problem is when I tried to add the imported-packages in the MAINFEST.MF file using the PDE's editor, the package from the fragemnt  doesn't show in the list!

Comment: Wudong - you may also need to add `Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true` to the fragment host (that is, Guice itself). Note that this is a pure-tooling header used by PDE, not an Eclipse or OSGi runtime header. See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html

Comment: what's the reason to avoid Require-Bundle wherever possible?

Comment: @Wudong - It creates explicit dependencies between bundles, which goes against standard OSGi practices.  Imports have no such explicit dependency and allows the OSGi framework to resolve its required classes at runtime.  This makes it easy to change the provider of any given class/package without impacting the bundle that requires it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the required package to `Import-Package`, you might need to add `Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true` to the manifest to prevent unresolved dependency error in PDE.