# Tycho downloads dependency but fails to resolve it

Tags: dependencies, osgi, tycho

I have an odd problem with Tycho 0.15.0. There are 8 dependencies in my `MANIFEST.MF` but Tycho fails to resolve one of them. The output looks like this:

```
[INFO] 1 operation remaining.
[INFO] Fetching org.eclipse.xtext.logging_1.2.15.v201206120633.jar (4kB of 10.12kB at 0B/s) from http://my.server.com/p2-3.7.2/plugins/
[INFO] Resolving class path of MavenProject: <...my project ...> @ <...path to my project...>/pom.xml
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle <...my project...> cannot be resolved
[ERROR] Resolution errors:
[ERROR] Bundle <...my project...> - Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtext.logging; bundle-version="1.2.15"
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Bundle <...my project...> cannot be resolved
Resolution errors:
Bundle <...my project...> - Missing Constraint: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.xtext.logging; bundle-version="1.2.15"
```

What I know:

1. The jar `org.eclipse.xtext.logging_1.2.15.v201206120633.jar` exists
2. The jar isn't corrupt
3. Tycho can download it from my p2 server (I have `~/.m2/repository/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.xtext.logging/1.2.15.v201206120633/org.eclipse.xtext.logging-1.2.15.v201206120633.jar` on my computer)
4. The `MANIFEST.MF` looks correct:

   ```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
   Bundle-Vendor: %providerName
   Bundle-Localization: fragment
   Fragment-Host: org.apache.log4j;bundle-version="[1.2.15,1.2.16)"
   Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
   Bundle-Name: %pluginName
   Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.xtext.logging;singleton:=true
   Created-By: 1.5.0_22-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
   Bundle-Version: 1.2.15.v201206120633
   Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
   Import-Package: org.eclipse.core.runtime,org.osgi.framework;version="1
   .5.0"
   ```
5. Tycho 0.16.0 has the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: org.eclipse.xtext.logging is a fragment. I do not believe you can depend on it directly. You should probably require org.apache.log4j

Comment: not sure if directly related, but org.eclipse.core.runtime is a split package
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fruntime_components.htm . You should disambiguate your Import-Package statement (or use Require-Bundle)

Comment: also, take a look at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=353116

Comment: @jsievers: I can't change the manifest of `org.eclipse.xtext.logging` but the bug looks interesting.

Comment: @Simon: okay, that would explain it. I would accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing this behaviour for the following reasons:

- `org.eclipse.xtext.logging` is a fragment, not a standalone bundle (you can see that because it has `Fragment-Host` in the `MANIFEST.MF` which defines the other bundle to which this one is a fragment of).
- The way fragments are encoded in p2, a `Require-Bundle` to a fragment can be resolved in p2. The p2-based dependency resolution determines which artifacts of the target platform are downloaded to the local Maven repository.
- A `Require-Bundle` to a fragment will not resolve in an OSGi server. For computing the class path (hence the console output `Resolving class path`), Tycho uses the Equinox resolver. That resolver detects correctly that [Require-Bundle to fragments is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141398/eclipse-osgi-bundle-reqiure-another-bundles-fragment).