# What is the right way to create JUnit tests for Eclipse fragments?

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

One of the most common uses of eclipse fragments is as a container for JUnit test classes. But how to write JUnit tests for Eclipse fragment when it plays another, more important role? For example, when it has platform specific code.

The problem is that it is impossible to create a fragment for a fragment. And you can't write tests for host plug-in to test the fragment because it doesn't even compile as a fragment is "merged" into a host only at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a satisfactory solution, however, you may want to consider these workarounds.

***Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI***

You can use the `Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI` manifest header like this

```
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true
```

It causes the packages exported by the fragment to be re-exported by the host bundle. Now you can create a test bundle that imports the desired packages and therefore has access to the public types in the fragment.

This isn't as close as test-fragments where you benefit from tests and production code using the same class loader that gives access to package-private types and methods. But you can at least test through the publicly accessible means.

Note, however, that this header is specific to Eclipse PDE and not part of the OSGi specification. Hence you are tied to this development environment. Furthermore, the packages of the fragment will be exported through its host bundle and will be visible not only for the test bundle but for all bundles.

***Java Library***

If your fragment has few dependencies and doesn't require the OSGi/Eclipse runtime you could consider treating it as a plain Java library w.r.t tests. Another sibling Java project could contain tests and have a project-dependency (*Properties > Java Build Path > Projects*) on the fragment project. Again, access to package-private members would not work.

And if you use a build tool like Maven/Tycho, some extra work would be required to declare dependencies and execute these tests during the build.

***Bndtools***

You could also look into [Bndtools](http://bndtools.org/) to see if this development tool fits your needs better than the Eclipse [Plug-in Development Environment (PDE)](https://www.eclipse.org/pde/).

Plain JUnit tests are held in a separate source folder in the same project as the production code. This would give your test code access to the production code in the same way as if test-fragments were used.

Bndtools also supports executing integration tests, though I doubt that you would have access to the fragment code other than through services or other API provided by the fragment.

For CI-builds, Bndtools projects usually use Maven or Gradle with the help of the respective `bnd`(http://bnd.bndtools.org/) plug-in. Just as Maven/Tycho is used to build and package PDE projects.

Since Bndtools is an IDE extension to develop OSGi bundles, it doesn't know about Eclipse plug-in specificities such as extensions declared in the `plugin.xml`. Hence there is no builder and editor for these artifacts. But if you are lucky, you may even be able to use the PDE builder to show error markers for invalid extensions and extension points.

Another downside that comes with having production- and test-code in the same project, is that pure test dependencies like JUnit, mock libraries, etc. are also visible for the production code at development time.

Of course, the produced (fragment) bundles do neither contain test code nor test dependencies.

However, Bndtools itself is developed with Bndtools. So there is proof that Bndtools can be used to write Eclipse plug-ins.

Comment: I tried to avoid the second option, which i knew about. However, i'll use this one, because currently i don't have access to host plugin to modify its header.
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI is a great thing. Didn't know about it. Thank you! Definitely will migrate to it, when have a chance.

Comment: Another possible solution came to my mind: Bndtools, please see the edited answer. Though it might be too far-fetched in your case, I'd nonetheless like to add it for the sake of completeness.

Comment: According to a comment by Neil Bartlett [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7141689/897024), `Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI` is "a pure-tooling header used by PDE, not an Eclipse or OSGi runtime header". So if you use it you shouldn't get tied to Equinox, just tied to Eclipse PDE.

Comment: @kapex thank you for the hint. I've changed the answer accordingly.